# jQuery to display URL parameters on a new line using %0A

Tags: javascript, newline, url-parameters

I am trying to display the parameters from the URL into a `hidden input field` to `li`. This bit is working fine and so is the ASCII value of spaces `%20`. i.e. `.html?line1=sample%20text%201&line2=sample%20text%202` outputs: `sample text 1 sample text 2`.

The problem is when I am trying to add `%0A` in the url to output long text to a new line.. this bit isn't working. I can't seem to get the parameters to display on to new lines. I looked at questions on here and on Google but I was unable to fix it.

This is the code I am working on:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
        try {
            q = location.search.substring(1);
            v = q.split("&");
            for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                p = v[i].split("=");
                if (p[0] == variable) {
                    if (p[1].indexOf('%20') != -1 && p[1].indexOf('%0A') != -1) {
                        return decodeURIComponent(p[1]);
                    }
                    else {
                        return p[1];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

getQueryVariable("line1");
getQueryVariable("line2");
getQueryVariable("line3");
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $('#input1').val(getQueryVariable('line1')).trigger('keyup');
        });
        $('#input1').on('keyup', function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $("li#one").text(value);
        });
    });

<input type="hidden" id="input1" />
<ul id="texts">  
        <li id="one"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if you're displaying it in a HTML document, as seems likely, then HTML doesn't take any notice of line feed characters - they are only for text documents. You'd need to swap your line feeds for HTML line breaks (`<br>`) to make it display a new line in a web page. But it's not clear, because you haven't shown us any code which would actually display your data. Also, why are you only decoding the string if it contains certain particular encoding characters? There are lots more possible characters which could be present and require decoding.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your suggestion. The problem is that sometimes the parameters on 'line1' can be long and to break it down. I want to add line breaks. I tried doing it on jQuery but it it's working for some reason =/. Let me update the whole code for you.

Comment: there's no jQuery here, it's just plain JavaScript in your function. The jQuery you've shown in the edit is not directly relevant to the issue. I know you want to add line breaks, but my point was about the environment in which you are displaying this information...in a HTML document, text-style line breaks do not work, so if you want the line breaks to be visible you must turn them into HTML line breaks before displaying the text. Also you didn't answer my point about only decoding a couple of the characters, that doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Also, since "input1" is a hidden field, why are you triggering a fake "keyup" event on it? I guess it maybe works in the code, but it's semantically nonsense, since a hidden field can never really trigger a keyup. You could just trigger any old custom event on it. Or why not just write the content directly into your `li` element without this layer of indirection? It doesn't seem to achieve much.

Comment: sorry about that.. at the moment am i only decoding it for testing purposes and adding a `newline` to the url is a requirement. Is there any way you could possible recommend on adding newline please? thanks.

Comment: yes, substitute the newlines for HTML line break characters, like I've said twice already. You can do it at the point of displaying the data if you like - there's no need to place those HTML characters into the URL. You can use a string replace to swap the `%0A` for `<br/>`.  Do you understand the difference between a text document and a HTML document?

Comment: I couldn't get the url parameters to display inside `li` so using an `input` field to replicate the value.

Comment: "I couldn't get the url parameters to display inside li so using an input field to replicate the value."...but then the next moment you take the value directly from the input and place it in the li anyway without changing it, so it achieves nothing useful.

Comment: I got it bro.. to replace `%0A` for <br>.. makes sense and yes i do know the different between a text and a HTML document. Regarding the `input` keyup thing i will do it properly once i get this newline issue resolved, as it makes sense to remove the `input` and directly display the value inside `li.` Sorry for any confusion but i am not an expert in javascript / jQuery. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I have got this `return decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\%20/g, " "));` working but when i try `return decodeURIComponent(pair[1].replace(/\%0A/g, "<br>"));` it doesn't create a new line. Could you please help or suggest on this issue. Thanks :) @ADyson

Comment: replace `$("li#one").text(value);` with `$("li#one").html(value);` - otherwise jQuery will format your HTML as plain text anyway.

Comment: @ADyson, thanks bro I missed this one out. Thanks for all your help and vital information you provided regarding with this issue. Have a great day :)